# get_taxonomy_labels only returns tags

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

In the archive template, I need to extract the taxonomy labels of the current taxonomy and I thought it should be straight forward like this

```
        if (is_tax()) {
            $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
            $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
            $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
            $term_labels = get_taxonomy_labels($current_term);
            if (is_super_admin()) {
                echo "$taxonomyName, $term_slug<br><pre>";
                var_dump($current_term);var_dump($term_labels);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
```

The dump of $current_term shows the correct taxonomy and term, however, the dump of $term_labels always shows labels for tags... I can't seem to find my error?!

Answer (score 0):

`get_taxonomy_labels()` needs a WP_Taxonomy object. You are passing it a WP_Term object.

Try:

```
$tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomyName);
$term_labels = get_taxonomy_labels($tax);
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the swift support!